# Create a bell shape with CSS

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

I am playing with shapes in css and want to make a traditional bell shape (think Christmas bell). 
Here's the general shape that I'm going for (though I really don't care about the balls on the top and bottom):

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/NeBtU/

```
#bell { 
  left:300px;
    position: relative;
}
#bell:before, #bell:after {
    position: absolute;
  content: "";
    left: 50px; top: 0;
    width: 180px;
    height:400px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 150px 150px 150px 20px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#bell:after { 
    left: 0; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg); 
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;
    border-radius: 150px 150px 20px 150px;
}
```

But, I'm not sure how to get that curved look on the side and bottom.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:  I've gotten closer by applying a radial-gradient to #bell:before and #bell:after.  This gives me the curve on the side, now I just need the curve on the bottom.  http://jsfiddle.net/NeBtU/2/

```
#bell {
    left:300px;
    position: relative;
}
#bell:before, #bell:after {
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    top: 0;
    width: 180px;
    height:400px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
}
#bell:before {
    left: 50px;
    border-radius: 150px 150px 20px 30px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    background: radial-gradient(-50px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #d3d3d3 20%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(-50px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #d3d3d3 20%);
}
#bell:after {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
    transform-origin:100% 0;
    border-radius: 150px 150px 30px 20px;
    background: radial-gradient(230px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #d3d3d3 20%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(230px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #d3d3d3 20%);
}
```

Comment: While I like css(We only support IE8 at work, so I don't get to use CSS3 :-( ), and think more things should be done with css. This seems like an obvious case to just use an image. Just my view.

Comment: Better yet, use an SVG!  If you do it as an inline SVG you can even animate it using CSS3 animations and transitions (obviously won't work in older browsers).

Comment: You're going to have to either a) use a number of short arcs with increasing or decreasing radii, or b) use parabolic math to achieve this. I agree that it's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: @isherwood I would be interested to see the solution regardless if someone could produce it :)

Comment: People watch Jerry Springer, too. ;-)

Comment: You might be able to do it with the fiddle you have combined with an upside down rounded tab [like Lea Verou posted about](http://lea.verou.me/2013/10/slanted-tabs-with-css-3d-transforms/)? It'd take two elements most likely

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at this one,

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NeBtU/16/)

[image: result shape]

css

```
  #bell {
    left:300px;
    top:20px;
    position: relative;
}
#bell:before, #bell:after {
    position: absolute;
    line-height:0;
    content:"\2315";
    color:#d3d3d3;
    font-size:100pt;
    text-indent:30px;
    top: 0;
    width: 180px;
    height:300px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
}
#bell:before {
    left: 50px;
    border-radius: 150px 150px 20px 30px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    background: radial-gradient(-50px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #d3d3d3 20%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(-50px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #d3d3d3 20%);
}
#bell:after {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
    transform-origin:100% 0;
    border-radius: 150px 150px 30px 20px;
    background: radial-gradient(230px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #d3d3d3 20%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(230px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #d3d3d3 20%);
    line-height:550px;
    content:"\25CF";
    color:#d3d3d3;
    font-size:130pt;
    text-indent:-15px;
}
```

ya its not exactly same as in the question, but came close.

**EDITED**

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NeBtU/18/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  The bottom still doesn't have the curve, but it's pretty good.  In Safari and Chrome, the ball at the bottom has extra artifacts.  But honestly, I don't care about the ball at the bottom.

Comment: added the bottom curve to the shape.

Answer (score 4):

You can work out the size of your bell in Illustrator (I drew one for you), but here's your proof of concept, as a `background-image` in `CSS`.

http://jsfiddle.net/itsmikem/Rs6aa/

Comment: From a practical point of view, this is probably the way to go.  But, since I'm experimenting with shapes in css, I'd rather not go the image route.  Though, I am amazed by how small the SVG code is.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I tryed to help you, with your way (Yes, It's hard!)
and that the best I got:

http://jsfiddle.net/NeBtU/1/

```
#bell { 
    left:100px;
    position: relative;
}
#bell:before, #bell:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 50px; top: 0;
    width: 320px;
    height:400px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 150px 150px 150px 20px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#bell:after { 
    left: 0; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg); 
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;
    border-radius: 150px 150px 20px 150px;

    line-height:740px;
    content:"\25CF";
    color:#d3d3d3;
    font-size:200pt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  It doesn't have the curves I'm looking for, but using the circle character is a great idea.