# Css Bordered Triangle

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm working on a project that needs a specific element. It is a Bordered Triangle like the picture below. Is it even possible to make this object in HTML/CSS.

[image]

Simple triangles only have straight borders

```css
.tri {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 80px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="tri"></div>
```

Comment: That looks more like a bell shape than a bordered triangle to me. If you are actually looking for a bordered triangle, have a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057669/border-within-border-css/18058163. Here is an answer about a shape which resembles the one in question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504215/create-a-bell-shape-with-css

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Paulie_D How many times a day do you post that or something similar?

Comment: Many, many times...because often new users don't bother to read and understand those guidleines or if they do they ignore them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved with SVG which is probably your best alternative.

```html
<svg width="150px" height="100px" viewbox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M5,0 Q8,3 8,8 Q5,10 2,8 Q2,3 5,0" fill="skyblue"></path>
</svg>
```

An alternative could be created with pseudo elements but is a very dirty way of achieving what you want.

```css
div {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid skyblue;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid skyblue;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 13px;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid skyblue;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 13px;
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it...very nice.